# water valve to toilet will not shut off and the water is running more and more even when off

Tags: water, toilet, valve

my toilet was being fix because one of my kids break it. the water valve was turn off but was leaking a lil bit then around 10:30 last night it sounding like my washer was being fill but it was coming from my bathroom the only way it would stop was to turn the main water line off but how do i get the water to turn off to the water valve to my toilet?

ps if there is a video that would help thank you!

Comment: There should be a shut-off valve on the wall behind the toilet that would enable you shut off water to the toilet. Are you saying that this valve is not shutting off the water? Sounds like you will have to call a plumber.

Comment: Are you saying the the water valve on the wall is turned off but it is still allowing some water to pass through to the toilet fill mechanism ?

Comment: You wanted a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydXW7D53suw  It has 2.4M views, that means its great right? Well... anyways. It sounds like someone fixed your fill valve, but did not do it correctly.Perhaps they did not know there are instructions on the package with the new valve, or perhaps those instructions are hard to follow. Either the FLAPPER is not seating all the way (debris or damage while replacing the fill valve), or the fill valve needs to be adjusted. That video gets you there. There are MANY videos you can watch. Other than this, you already figured out how to get water off.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me yesterday I kid you not.  Not rushing water but a slow drip that accelerated overnight and went down thru the wall all the way to the basement.

The problem was that the rubber washer in the toilet fill valve had corroded because of water.  No problem when attached to the toilet but when I needed to it turn off it could not seal completely and then got worse over a few days.  .

Interested parties mandated that I call a plumber, and for $450 2 guys came and put a new toilet valve shutoff on the water supply line.  It is very nice. The other option would have been for me to bring the old toilet valve shutoff to the hardware store, match it with a new $15, bring that home and put it on.

Benefit would have been savings of $335.  Risk would have been that I screw it up somehow and cause colossal house-destroying leak.  You do that once and people remember...

Answer (score 2):

I've renovated a few houses, and whenever I replace a toilet the first thing I do is replace the shut-off valve.

Unless they are frequently used, the older style shut-offs with the round handles tend to fail after sitting in the same position for years.  Assuming you *can* still shut them off, they'll either start dripping when they are shut off, or start dripping when you turn them back on again.

The newer style shut-off valves are simpler and much more reliable, requiring only a quarter turn between on and off.

---

Replacing the valves is easy and inexpensive, *except when it isn't*.

I once tried to replace an old, very green and corroded valve in a dark corner.  The supply pipe was too long anyway, so rather than attempting to de-solder the connection, I simply cut it off with a pipe cutter.

The cutting took longer than normal, and once I had it off I discovered why.  The supply pipe wasn't standard copper, but brass, with threaded connections, and I had just destroyed it.

There was no way I could un-cut the pipe, and since it was thicker than copper pipe I couldn't attach any shutoff valve to it.  To make things perfect, there were two families in the house that now had no water at all:  time to call a *real* plumber and fork out the $$$.